# Is there a way to route network traffic inside AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

I have an ec2 host in AWS Ireland. I am connecting to a host that is near AWS Tokyo, but not within AWS Tokyo.

I want my TCP packets to enter the AWS network at Tokyo, and then be routed over the AWS network to Ireland. I've noticed that this is both lower latency and higher bandwidth than routing over the open internet. However, it seems that the packets instead flow over the open internet until Ireland.

Is there a way to force the networking route to enter AWS at Tokyo instead of Ireland?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use-case for Global Accelerator. Additional charges apply.

Answer (score 1):

In AWS routing the destination must be the target host, if it is not AWS will discard the packets. The exception to this rule is with NAT routing, which explicitly for a NAT instance you must disable the source/destination check.

If you explicitly want it to join at Tokyo you would need to configure your endpoint in the Tokyo region, then have it receive the payload before it then forwards it to the Ireland VPC (using a [peering connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html)). To forward the payload you would need an application that forwards this to the region.

If you're instead trying to make use of the closest edge location to the user then you would want to either look at using [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) or [Global Accelerator](https://aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/). Both of these will use [local AWS PoP](https://www.infrastructure.aws/) and then forward traffic via the AWS backbone to reach its target.